# Style material slider ticks

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, slider

Using @angular /material 12.2

I want to add some style (width and color) to these ticks
I could change the tick height by modifying classes .mat-slider-ticks and .mat-slider-ticks-container, but it's not working for width and color.

From the angular/components source code, I found this :

```
.mat-slider-ticks {
@include vendor-prefixes.private-background-clip(content-box);
background-repeat: repeat;
box-sizing: border-box;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity variables.$swift-ease-out-duration variables.$swift-ease-out-timing-function;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with the following rules. Note that I wrapped the `mat-slider` in a `div` with the `custom-slider` class as a way to avoid using `!important`. However, you can include just the inner rules in your global style if you don't mind the `!important` override.

```
.custom-slider {
  .mat-mdc-slider .mdc-slider__tick-mark--active,
  .mat-mdc-slider .mdc-slider__tick-mark--inactive {
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygsg95?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: This is only for @angular/material 15+ but thanks for the help.

For those wondering you can achieve that by modifying the background-image and putting a gradient of your choice. For some reason the last tick will not be styled, you can style it with adding css to mat-slider-wrapper:after

Comment: @MaxM sorry, missed your version number there. Nice to see you got something working

Comment: I had to add ng-deep (i.e: `.custom-slider ::ng-deep { ... }`), but this worked for me